# MongoDB server keeps timing out

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have recently moved to a Mongo server that is running on a CentOS Google Cloud machine I've setup myself (the Mongo service started with systemct).  Previously I've been running my mongo DB either locally, or via a server hosted by mlab.

Everything is working fine, except my client keeps getting StopIterator exceptions errors on any non-trivial query. I never encountered these previously, either running local or with the mlab server.  Is there a timeout setting on the server I should be setting? (the client timeout settings don't seem to effect the issue)

Comment: Do you get the same thing connecting via the Mongo shell?  Have you tried looking at your Mongo log to see if it indicates any problems?

Comment: I can't repro using the CLI. Bit there is an obvious hitch when I dump all the queries like this (at about the point in the query where the timeout error occurs in my python code). So I guess the timeout is occurring but it is recovering automatically?

Comment: Nothing obvious in the logs: 
                          "2017-07-16T21:22:04.905+0000 I NETWORK  [conn3] end connection 98.210.207.17:64084 (2 connections now open)",
              "2017-07-16T21:22:04.965+0000 I NETWORK  [conn4] end connection 98.210.207.17:64086 (1 connection now open)",
              "2017-07-16T21:22:10.037+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 98.210.207.17:49167 #6 (2 connections now open)",
              "2017-07-16T21:22:11.457+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 98.210.207.17:49170 #7 (3 connections now open)"

Comment: Maybe post your code? If you've had the same code working against a different server, there might not be anything that we can figure out.

Comment: OK, so weirdly I noticed this issue only happens when I am running the client code in the Visual Studio debugger. So I guess it is nothing to do with the server. I guess some subtle environment or interpreter difference. Very strange as it happens 100% of the time even in a trivial example that just creates the mongoclient and runs the query (which runs fine from command line)

Answer (score 0):

So I have (sort of) answered my question. The reason my client app was dying was I was running from the Visual Studio debugger.  That was catching the StopIterator and asserting, even though (I think) the StopIterator exception was being handled by the pymongo library which is re-trying and continuing successfully. If I disable that StopIterator exception in the "Python Exceptions" section of the VisualStudio "Exception Settings" panel, then my client code will continue and complete successfully.

That said, I am pretty sure this was not happening before I setup my own Mongo server (as well as the assert in VS there is an noticeable hitch when that exception occurs, both in my python code and in the mongo command line client). So I still believe there is something I am doing wrong with how I setup my Mongo server, so any suggestions on that would be welcome!